# TypeScript: Accept all Object keys that map to a specific type

Tags: typescript, types

Given an object type (or class type), I want to write a function that accepts the object and a list of its keys. However, I only want to allow keys that map to a value of a specific type, e.g. only strings.

Example:

```js
function shouldOnlyAcceptStringValues(o, key) {
    // Do something with o[key] that depends on the assumption that o[key] has a specific type, e.g. string
}

const obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: "test",
    c: "bla"
}

const key = "c" as const;
shouldOnlyAcceptStringValues(obj, key);  // b and c should be accepted as keys, a not.
```

I know a way to enforce that `key` actually exists on `o` (regardless of the type of `o[key]`):

```js
function shouldOnlyAcceptStringValues<T>(o: T, key: keyof T) {
    // Do something with o[key] that depends on the assumption that o[key] has a specific type, e.g. string
}
```

However, this would also allow the use of `key="a"` although that maps to a number.

What I need is something like this:

```js
function shouldOnlyAcceptStringValues<T, K extends keyof T, T[K] extends string>(o: T, key: K)
```

But that is of course not valid TypeScript code.

Is there a trick how to make that work? I need a way to further refine the set of keys `keyof T`. The body of the function should then know that `o[key]` is a string without explicitly checking the type inside the function. Is that somehow possible?

Comment: Follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61787237/typescript-error-when-passing-an-array-in-a-variable-rather-than-direcly-to-a-f

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want something that works from both the caller's point of view and from the implementer's point of view, you can do this:

```
function shouldOnlyAcceptStringValues<K extends PropertyKey>(
  o: Record<K, string>, key: K
) {
    const okay: string = o[key];
}
```

This is sort of looking at your constraint backwards; instead of constraining `key` to be the right keys from `obj`, you are constraining `obj` to be an object whose value type at `key` is a `string`.  You can see that `okay` is accepted as a `string`, and things work from the caller's side also:

```
shouldOnlyAcceptStringValues(obj, "a"); // error!
// ------------------------> ~~~
// Argument of type '{ a: number; b: string; c: string; }' is 
// not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<"a", string>'.

shouldOnlyAcceptStringValues(obj, "b"); // okay
shouldOnlyAcceptStringValues(obj, "c"); // okay
```

The only snag is that the error on the first call is probably not on the argument you expect; it's complaining about `obj` and not `"a"`.  If that's okay, great.  If not, then you could change the call signature to be the sort of constraint you're talking about:

---

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never }[keyof T]
function shouldOnlyAcceptStringValues2<T>(o: T, key: KeysMatching<T, string>): void;
function shouldOnlyAcceptStringValues2<K extends PropertyKey>(
  o: Record<K, string>, key: K
) {
    const okay: string = o[key];
}
```

The `KeysMatching<T, V>` type function takes a type `T` and returns just those keys whose values are assignable to `V`.  And so the call signature will specify `T` for `o` and `KeysMatching<T, string>` for `key`.  Note how I've written that call signature as a single [overload](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) and the implementation signature is the same as before.  If you don't do that then the compiler is unable to understand that for generic `T` that `T[KeysMatching<T, string>]` is assignable to `string`; it's a higher-order type inference the compiler can't make:

```
function shouldOnlyAcceptStringValuesOops<T>(o: T, key: KeysMatching<T, string>) {
    const oops: string = o[key]; // error!
    // -> ~~~~
    // Type 'T[{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? K : never; }[keyof T]]' 
    // is not assignable to type 'string'. 
}
```

See [microsoft/TypeScript#30728](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30728) for more information.

So in the overloaded version we let the caller see the constraint on `key` and the implementation see the constraint on `obj`, which works out better for everyone:

```
shouldOnlyAcceptStringValues2(obj, "a"); // error!
// ------------------------------> ~~~
// Argument of type '"a"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"b" | "c"'

shouldOnlyAcceptStringValues2(obj, "b"); // okay
shouldOnlyAcceptStringValues2(obj, "c"); // okay
```

Now the compiler complains about `key` instead of `obj`.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAsAKBnmAhgFwwCMANDvjPCQERQCm0dlu+w98ANgXTgF8cOAGYBXMMCgBLcDAgALEGO4ATAPJhuATwCCwYIwAOUAMpQATtLABzAGoFuY5gB4A0jEYAPJmFUQYAAULECNGCyhtN0ZtAD4AChASACVGUAtVd3J5S2sbWOyAaxiSNwBKDCoOcGg4QoJtEmgrW1Q4AG1i7QBdAG5BYWxFZTVNHX1DE3MW+0dnCESkbLo+Mt6YAHoNzwsQiwBCHC2YAFoz84vLq-PYmAA-B6Pt3QsbMQBbRjBYEBEYSLCMAA5OhCCQwB94OF1rQcjN1pw4Xl1gIgTBpAEnjAwCBYAQIBBpDYwAQeIx-iAYEYCBYCJ8mBY4H8AeSgal0pkVqwkbZYkCAHSDYYqDRaPQGYxmXK2BxOZiLRDLeB0NabbYgeraHDC0ZiiaS6Z5WXzBXLYAq9bHDUNQYsmDRbQQACyBCgwAUeRcABVsnZbmhQe0PNYYF1fjAvd0SF6g91PD4vv4YHYYAB+e0wcGMABu4RgAk6MXDkdEEiksjA8iUIrG4smUpmxuYACZvQkkhGiiV7TFna73Z6fTz8mUSNmQNJVP1sOJJDI5DrReMJVNpbM5RBWx5vL4k8FQuFIg72yk0iAMllhwVQ93ypV2HhQJAfpqmmu2iBCz1p0JsKW5xWVYjEudYGmuTYQOooQQG2iTRl2jQ9o6Lpuh6tjetkzR5LEFRYA+MBPrUIDQW+Mwfl+fRqjseyHPhxwnLcDyPHR2xetogJAjGgbBpWYZ-JG0axvGu4BFhrTph4Wa5hYKJfsW3TdGiVR4McGLYrihAEkSJJkhS-zsayYk2AKMCALwbgC0ewMf7WYutb6qujZzC2powFyqrHOENFYtcPm+VcjHMccLxvJ83xMvpHFcmiak4niWnEqS3DklAlLUrS9J5uGdpAnQyowAAPq55pAkK1a6su9aGjKTmbi5uUWlR1pakMZUgfZDZGjVzZ1ea7nqpqOBAA)

Comment: (Not OP) reading your answers is always an elucidating pleasure.

Comment: Thank you. I have some questions. The first is about the first solution: By using `o: Record<K, string>`, don't I only accept objects that only have keys which map to strings? Clearly, your code works, so apparently my assumption is wrong, but I don't really understand why. Is `Record<K, string>` a supertype of `<Record, any>` which would explain why objects containing more than only string values are accepted.

Comment: `Record<K, string>` means "for the keys in `K`, the values are `string`".  It doesn't have any implications about keys *not* in `K`.  Object types in TypeScript aren't ["exact"](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936); they are allowed to have extra properties (the [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) done in certain circumstances notwithstanding).  So a value of type `{a: number, b: string, c: string}` is assignable to a variable of type `{b: string}` aka `Record<'b', string>`.

Comment: Hi, I am wondering how to also accept `string | null` properties. While the above works for `KeysMatching<MyObject, string>` and string values, it does not work for `KeysMatching<MyObject, string | null>` or `KeysMatching<MyObject, Maybe<string>>`, where `Maybe<T> = T | null`. `Maybe<string>` values are not accepted. I tried to alter it to `{
  [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends Maybe<V> ? K : never;
}[keyof T]` but that does not work either. Any idea?

Comment: @Steinroe without a [mcve] it's hard to say; what is `MyObject`?  I couldn't easily reproduce, so ‍♂️. Generally speaking comments aren't the best place to do this, but if you can manage to get a reproducible example for me via something like [the TS Playground link shortener](https://tsplay-dev.now.sh/) I might give it a shot. Otherwise you should consider opening a new question if you can't figure it out.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the offer! While creating the sample I realised that the prop types of MyObjects properties was null | undefined | string - so adding undefined to the union fixed it. Thanks!