# Typescript error 2345 when passing array as variable instead of directly

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

*Question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61787237/typescript-error-when-passing-an-array-in-a-variable-rather-than-direcly-to-a-f) but both the solutions provided don't address nor solve the issue*

I was following some TypeScripts examples about generics, in the specific [this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-generics-in-typescript).

The example is pretty straightforward:

```js
function pickObjectKeys<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, keys: K[]) {
  let result = {} as Pick<T, K>
  for (const key of keys) {
    if (key in obj) {
      result[key] = obj[key]
    }
  }
  return result
}

const language = {
  name: "TypeScript",
  age: 8,
  extensions: ['ts', 'tsx']
}

const ageAndExtensions = pickObjectKeys(language, ['age', 'extensions'])
```

This works. However, if passing the array as a variable, like so:

```js
const keys = ['age', 'extensions']

...

pickObjectKeys(language, keys)
```

the TypeScript compiler gives error 2345:

```
Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '("age" | "extensions" | "name")[]'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"age" | "extensions" | "name"'.
```

What's the catch? How to address this issue?

Comment: `keys` is inferred as `string[]`, not `["age", "extensions"]` or `("age" | "extensions")[]`.

Comment: @caTS Ah, makes sense. So how would you address it? Assume that you may want to be able to pass a variable to the function

Comment: `const keys : ("age" | "extensions")[] = ["age", "extensions"]` or `const keys = ["age" | "extensions"] as ("age" | "extensions")[]`. Because if you just do `const keys = ["age", "extensions"]` it's totally legal to do `keys.push("foobar")` but that would cause an error in `pickObjectKeys`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, consider making `keys` readonly:

```
function pickObjectKeys<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, keys: readonly K[]) {
```

this will allow you to pass readonly arrays now (previously it would've errored).

The easiest way to get around this is to use a const assertion:

```
const keys = ['age', 'extensions'] as const; // readonly ["age", "extensions"]

pickObjectKeys(language, keys); // OK
```

but you could also cast to `["age", "extensions"]` or `("age" | "extensions")[]`. However, that does mean you would repeat yourself, so I suggest staying with `as const`.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/ND2V1W)