# Check that arguments of a function are the keys of a correct type in a type parameter

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to build a nice, Rails-like form builder in React with TypeScript. I'm fascinated by the possible compile compile-time checks, and I'm keen to see if there is a certain one I can implement. I'm not sure how to phrase this question abstractly, but I think a small example will illustrate it better anyway.

Let's say I have a generic `Input` type that is an object with some properties. I'd like to have a function, `numericField`, that takes an input object and key `K` where `Input[K]` is of type `number`. If I pass a mistyped key or a key of type string, I'd like to get a compiler error.

For example:

```js
interface Person {
  name: string
  age: number
}
```

I'd like to get the following:

```js
decimalField<Person>({input: person, key: 'age'})  // works
decimalField<Person>({input: person, key: 'agge'}) // compiler error
decimalField<Person>({input: person, key: 'name'}) // compiler error
```

I've managed to do so with the following type:

```js
export type PropertiesOfSubtype<T, P> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: Exclude<T[K], undefined | null> extends P ? K : never
}[keyof T]
```

If I define `decimalField` as:

```js
function decimalField<Input>(props: {input: Input, key: PropertiesOfType<Input, number>})
```

..it kinda works. But there is an issue.

I'd like typescript to know that `input[key]` returns a number. Currently it doesn't. I think there might be a way to rewrite it where it can typecheck as TS knows it will return a string.

I guess my question is: is there a better way to do this?

P.P.: Here's a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=39&ssc=1&pln=39&pc=158#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyxyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmRJcj1pAruQEbQvF4ANywNIAOW58oNEFP4BfAgQgAPAA6iwyMAE91KVFCwGoYYBAwB5GAGVOPPQYA8AFQA0aAHzIAvPhYAbQBpZFBkAGsIXSwYZFcAXQBaAH4aAFFVBAAbTgATCDcQhM9OEAKYUAg85AAfLmzsnzVIcow0ZBTkUNkIIUVAqJi4xOUYMoRzHGQChGByOGyAMQtsvOcASRB1TjAvAAp1Y3UMGjww7d2aLZ2wTyGaIxNoc0sbe0d9QpvdzzleaA+BQASgCJGQCBwdGQQkWnBQ-lAt0G0QSAmQUAgYE4UFwACIAO4ACzgkH6UDxBCUBEhIGhpmwuH8eDIlBoAHIAFJYIm4AAiWAg7M8bA4AGYxZ5hKJgBJ5DJkABGAAM1Nm80WKwga325yRV2QDJw92iHNF7OQIII6oWy1WeV1F1uNCNIBNujNjHYFqtNs19sd+rALswxsipuQ7NZQstwOUtOh2TgfGy7WZ6OjHPEFCF7nRoo5AEFvVSxhMprg-XbtXkAEybS53ZAAGWT2owByOJlO+CdBp+TaTKZ7reH7sexxeFmsdgcTm+jb+8p8ADJw8MW23UyCaHAQLoCOMQJNgNMq1q1vWB55R+3O8ce3rG9dF8gh+2aLfU+O0JOzNP3jnL4G1uJcASgLxPHfbIaDoBgQEYHdkD3A8jxPM8IDmW0LzrEDfk3Yd727M4+2DZBrzfLcRyon8nlMV4Zw+ec8Kbf5pEgyiUzSWh6CYWNd33MESATbRYVyBFSJRXQ0XBETOO1Px5OyOp6mgjApJkkhMWxXFkEJEkyWgSlqWtTCNWrS9A2fQ1QzdJSMB-dlzVjcFXLc9yPI8gB6Lz4iJaAUGAdo4CU5AYFEHQiSC0ysP9Gtays50bKgRkoJo9dPVzJSi3YABCH1QU8oqSB85ArHJBg8j4sB-JmCB4E4bJtGgmLzJwhKnyS100rHDLI2lMQIEkcDhWyyMljgERBq4EaXNK8QsDqhqmqUzxsGQHAUAQPdkD4WgDDmSpqla7D7Q60iQxSsM1McgbZSG+UCuK57wVKgBhLByHUYBshQcxKGQaBjCgMI4hqgKwnaEBFoqOBGu0Pcamh-azKOmpoKAA) with the example, with what my next step is – an optional/required argument depending if there's a predefined label or on for the field.

Comment: Does `key: Record<PropertiesOfType<Input, number>, number>` help?

Comment: It does not. I'm not sure what you're referring to with `PropertiesOfType`, but if it is the type I've written above, it would evaluate to a type `{age: number}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript: Accept all Object keys that map to a specific type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61764867/typescript-accept-all-object-keys-that-map-to-a-specific-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say you want `input[key]` to be understood to be a `number`, you mean inside the implementation of `decimalField()`, right?   Inside the implementation, `Input` is an unspecifed generic type parameter.  When types depend on unspecified generic type parameters, the compiler will have a better time understanding that `input[key]` is of type `number` if `input`'s type is explicitly constrained to `Record<typeof key, number>`.  Theoretically the compiler could figure that out itself, but in practice it doesn't perform such higher order analysis with unspecified generics.

You could possibly write it this way:

```
type PropertyHaver<T, P> = { [K in PropertiesOfSubtype<T, P>]: P };
```

And then `decimalField`'s generic type parameter can be constrained like this:

```
function decimalField<Input extends PropertyHaver<Input, number>>(
    props: { input: Input, key: PropertiesOfSubtype<Input, number> }) {
    const value: number = props.input[props.key]
    return "whatever"
}
```

The implementation understand that `input[key]` is a `number` now.  (Note, it's really `props.input[props.number]`.)

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyxyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmRJcj1pAruQEbQvF4ANywNIAOW58oNEFP4BfAgQgAPAA6iwyMAE91KVFCwGoYYBAwB5GAGVOPPQYA8AFQA0aAHzIAvPgFkAG0AaWRQZABrCF0sGGRXAF0AWgB+GgBRVQQAG04AEwg3UMTPThBCmFAIfOQAHy4cnJ81SAqMNGRU5DDZCCFFIOjY+KTlJ0NjUz0ACTgBqDdPVB9-PGCwiKMTaHNLG3tHfSKPb0SaVGQFAG5lGHKEcxxkQoRgcjgcgDELHPznACSIHUnG0rQg7TQU12ujmC0BwNBnjkvGgXi8AApAuophgaOtQCCwDQgUTPMMLtCzBZrHYHBMEWSuKioD4FABKAIkZAIHB0ZBCT6cDgo6R+ZA4kwYAB0hNBQUl6hlw0SgSgEDAnCguAARAB3AAWcEgCx1BCUBF5IH5pmwuDWpAoHAA5AApLAG3AAESwEGdnjYHAAzEHPMJRMAJPIZMgAIwABiuyle70+PwgfwxBMRxIlmBw5JiNGdgedV3ZBBTH2+v3yWfCOZotoLUSLyBLjHYZY5lYgb2r6cz2aJTfzIELumLZEo3YrBCAA)