# Type for all keys which would give numeric values

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say I want to write a `sortBy` function, that takes a list of `T`s and a key of T to sort the list by.

To properly work I want the key to only accept keys of T that are numeric.

I have this, but I don't know how to restrict `Key` so that `T[Key]` refers to a number:

```
const sortBy = <T, Key extends keyof T>(items: T[], key: Key) { 
  // impl
}
```

I played around with this, but could not get it to work:

```
type NumericAttributesOf<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends number ? T[K] : never
}
```

#### Update:

based on the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61764867/typescript-accept-all-object-keys-that-map-to-a-specific-type) this is what I ended up with:

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never
}[keyof T]

function sortBy<T>(items: T[], key: KeysMatching<T, number>): T[]
function sortBy<K extends PropertyKey>(
  items: Record<K, number>[],
  key: K,
): Record<K, number>[] {
  return [...items].sort((a, b) => a[key] - b[key])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with

```
type NumericAttributesOf<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends number ? T[K] : never
}
```

1. `T[K] extends number ? T[K] : never` selects **value** type while you're looking for key type, so it should be `[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends number ? K : never`
2. The result of mapped type is an "object", you need to use lookup to extract union of allowed keys.

Here's a working example:

```
type NumericKeys<T> = { 
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends number ? K : never 
}[keyof T]

const sortBy = <T, Key extends NumericKeys<T>>(items: T[], key: Key) => { 
  // impl
}

sortBy([{ str: 'str', num: 1}], 'str') // Error: Argument of type '"str"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"num"'
sortBy([{ str: 'str', num: 1}], 'num') // OK
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwgJwJYGMDSEQGcA8AKgHxQC8UA3gFBRQDamUqAdlANY4D2AZlIQF0AXP0YCoEAB7AILACa4oLRACMUUAPxQmIlhABuKagF96nEL34Dq1dFxa5gUXF2TAAQiHJQiAGm04EtKyCrCIKBjYeETExAAUqDIIuCKE9AL%205iJRAJTkpDR0APRFzAhgADYmNi5unnH0lM7AyCIA5I7Ibf7KCCIAjFDGGVAdLW15JVAAosjIriIAgsgA5uEsTpagkKMARJ27bcyKLFxOAIa4uKgrLOcqFdDAXFBg58jnSDLIUFvg0G1dr1DtRah4QA0mp12p1ukpEAMhiM2r0JlApgB5TBAA)

Comment: That seems to work quite well! Thanks a lot. In the implementation I try to access the key of an item, but instead of giving me `number` as a type, I get the `Key[T]`, which I also get without the whole restriction to numeric keys only :\

Comment: In the end I found a solution based on the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61764867/typescript-accept-all-object-keys-that-map-to-a-specific-type

Comment: Thanks Aleksey, will accept your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution

```
const sortBy = <T, Key extends keyof T>(items: T[], key: T[Key] extends number ? Key : never) => { 
  // impl
}

sortBy([{
  name: 'Test',
  age: 20
}], 'name') // ERROR

sortBy([{
  name: 'Test',
  age: 20
}], 'age') // Ok
```

Explanation:

This code stores the type of the second parameter in `Key`. It then restricts `Key` to keys where `T[Key]` is a number.

Comment: Hmmm. It does not work for me.

I think the `NumericAttributesOf` is wrong. `keyof NumericAttributesOf<{ name: string; age: number }>` gives me `name | age`, where it should only be `age`.